# Rails - What's the best way to route duplicate slugs with a forward slash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, slug, friendly-id

I'm using `friendly_id` 5.2.

By default, it just appends a random UUID on the end for what would be duplicate slugs (`post-60948cdd-d73c-4b77-9676-ecdf7727c396`), but with the `sequentially_slugged` method you can just turn it back to how it worked in version 4 where it appends a dash and then a number on the end (`post-7`).

What's the best way to replace the dash with a forward slash? `post/7` (ordered by when they were created).

As far as I understand, you'd want to allow duplicate slugs in the gem and then just change the routes on Rails' end.

Answer (score 0):

As I read in the [documentation](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Slugged/Configuration.html#sequence_separator-instance_method)

> ## [Instance Attribute Summary](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Slugged/Configuration.html#sequence_separator-instance_method)
>
> - (Object) `sequence_separator`
>   The string used to separate a slug base from a numeric sequence.
> - (Object) `slug_column`
>   The column that will be used to store the generated slug.
> - (Object) `slug_generator_class`
>   Returns the value of attribute `slug_generator_class`.
>
> ## Instance Attribute Details
>
> - (Object) `sequence_separator`
>   The string used to separate a slug base from a numeric sequence.
>
> You can change the default separator by setting the `sequence_separator` configuration option.
>
> Returns:
>
> String The sequence separator string. Defaults to "-".

Comment: The forward slash throws a wrench into the gears, it isn't like other characters. The slug is generated fine but Rails doesn't know how to route it.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard how is the slug generated?

Comment: `"post/2"`, just like that

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard are you using singular `resource :post` or you are mistaking `resources :posts` and the route is `posts/:id`

Comment: Second one, `resources :posts, path: ""`